# How to update the tag using DOM Parser in java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

```
<root>
<title>Title<id>244</id></title>
<value>sample</value>
</root>
```

In the above xml, i have to update the content of title tag with another value say "Hello".So that my XML becomes like

```
<root>
<title>Hello<id>244</id></title>
<value>sample</value>
</root>
```

But I'm not to achieve the same by using DOM Parser in Java.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Use XSLT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019926/replacing-the-xml-node-text-using-xslt-and-java

Comment: I'm getting a XML Document as a input where I have to replace 'Title' with 'Hello'

Comment: I can't use XSLT, my program won't know about the contents of the XML until it traverse thru it

Comment: Why you like work with DOM parser? DOM name suggests clearly that is used  mostly for xml parsing , for updating the xml , why you should not with try other API of java ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the value of a xml tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303798/changing-the-value-of-a-xml-tag)

Answer (score -1):

So when u get the String tags simple swap the main string what u parse like this:
   String stringToParseXML = oldString.replace("Title244","Hello244");